# Running AOSP on Samsung device

Tags: android, android-source, samsung-mobile

I cloned the AOSP (pie) and made it successfully. Everything was fine on emulators. But I got problems when trying to release it on Samsung j5.
I have followed two approaches. First, I tried to run it directly, but after several searches, I found that the `fastboot` mode isn't available for Samsung devices (Actually for devices that use snapdragon families).
So I decided to create an OTA release through this command and install it by using TWRP :

```
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
```

But again, I fell into trouble when trying to generate OTA.

```
ERROR: --- target build has specified no recovery ---
```

I found `recovery.img` not generated. I thought it must be related to my `lunch` configs, so I tried with some different lunch mode :

```
lunch aosp_blueline-userdebug
```

```
lunch aosp_arm64-userdebug
```

```
lunch aosp_arm64-eng
```

But the result didn't any changes. So I found that I must find a Samsung related lunch devices, but until now I didn't find anything useful.

So the main problem I have is how to release AOSP on a Samsung device?